# The name "div" cannot be found ... Huh? Why?

Tags: alloy

In this module I use the Alloy "div":

```
module test

one sig Test {
     t: Int
} {
   t = div[4,2]
}

run {}
```

Executing that works fine.

I created another module, which uses the first module:

```
module hope

open test

sig A {}

run {}
```

Executing that results in the following error message:

> The name "div" cannot be found.

Why am I getting the error message? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug with a simple workaround. You need to explicitly import the `util/integer` module in your first model.

See [Alloy built-in integer math functions don't work in imported files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573298/alloy-built-in-integer-math-functions-dont-work-in-imported-files)

Comment: Ah! Okay. Thank you @Loïc Gammaitoni